# Add the type of the variable in a for..of loop on a Readable

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following loop:

```
for await (const element of readable) {
```

`readable` inherit of the `Readable` class. But I know that the objects in this `Readable` will always be of class `MyClass`.

How can I say to Typescript that `element` is of `MyClass` type ? With the current code, Typescript thinks that `element` is of `any` type.

Of course I can cast it in a new variable like this :

```
for await (const e of readable) {
    const element: MyClass = e;
```

But I wonder if there is a more elegant way.

Comment: I think you can do `for await (const e of (readable as AsyncIterable<MyClass>))`
As far as I know Readable is not generic

Comment: @ArtyomSmirnov Nice one. I can also add it directly in my `readable` class to avoid to cast it each time I need a loop. Post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast readable to `AsyncIterable<MyClass>`

```
for await (const e of (readable as AsyncIterable<MyClass>))
```